# How do I load a list via a data set from SQL Server into ListView?

Tags: c#

I have what seems to be a simple question but its killing me trying to find out.

I have a form in which I have a ListView. In this ListView I would like to populate it with data from a SQL Server 2008 database table.

```
public void LoadList()
{
   DataTable dtable = budget_MainDataSetReceipt.Tables["Receipt"];
   listView1.Items.Clear();

   for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      DataRow drow = dtable.Rows[i];

      if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
      {
         ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["ReceiptID"].ToString());
         lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["DateCleared"].ToString());
         lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["CategoryID"].ToString());
         lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Amount"].ToString());
         lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Store"].ToString());
         lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["DateEntered"].ToString());

         listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
      }
   }
}
```

I keep getting an

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

error, and I can't figure out why. There are about 5 rows of data in my database, so in my mind, there should be 5 rows of data within the list view.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I can post more code if that would be helpful.

I have tried calling the `LoadList()` method in several ways:

- Before the method itself
- With the `InitializeComponent()` method
- I have tried the following syntax

  ```
  this.LoadList(); 
  this.Form1.LoadList();`
  ```

I have also tried to initialize the DataTables type with the following:

```
DataTables dt = new DataTables //did not work
```

Comment: On what line do you get the null reference exception? Could you show some sample data?

Comment: I get the error on the following:
`DataTable dtable = budget_MainDataSetReceipt.Tables["Receipt"]`

Comment: Well that would mean that `budget_MainDataSetReceipt` is null.

Comment: Have you tried to use a numerical index (just for testing)? Maybe he can't find the table with that name.

Comment: Just to be certain, have you loaded the dataset with data before attempting to access it to fill your listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch would be: you're assuming for all columns in your `DataRow` that they're present and not null - that's a bit of a dangerous assumption.

I would change your assignments to use a method that checks for `DBNull` before returning the string:

```
public string SafeGetString(DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    if(row[columnName] != null && row[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        return row[ColumName].ToString();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

so your could would look like:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(SafeGetString(drow, "ReceiptID"));
lvi.SubItems.Add(SafeGetString(drow, "DateCleared"));
// and so forth
```

This way, if any of the columns should contain a `NULL`, you would get back an empty string - instead of running into a `NULL.ToString()` that causes the error you're seeing.

Comment: +1 for the tip with non-existing columns, but his comment tells he's getting the error on the line 'DataTable dtable = budget_MainDataSetReceipt.Tables["Receipt"]'.

Comment: I realized what I am looking for can't actually happen in the context I was attempting, but I do appreciate the help. I redid my ListViewItem the way you stated and it does work, so this will be the accepted answer. I'm sure I'll have many more C# related questions, so I appreciate all the help.